# Keyboard beeing shown when pressing tab before button

Tags: android-studio

I'm very new to Android studio, and i'm trying to build a simple app that when I click a button, it does some calculations. The problem is that when I press tab on the last `EditText` before the button, the button become focused and a keyboard is shown, I just want the button to remain unfocusable so when the user input every necessary data, he can just click the `button`

What I tried is setting the property `focusable` and `focusableInTouchMode` to false but none of them seem to work and I havent found no other option that made sense for me.

What can I do to stop this behaviour?

Edit: 
Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.rodolfo.trekking">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit 2:
XML Layout:

```
ersion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/edTempo"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/edTrecho"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/btCalcular" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/btCalcular"/>
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/edVelocidade"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/velocidade"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edTempo" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:text="@string/trecho"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edTrecho"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edTrecho" android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edVelocidade"/>
    <TextView
            android:text="@string/tempo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/edTempo"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/edTempo"/>
    <Button
            android:text="@string/calcular"
            android:layout_width="210dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:id="@+id/btCalcular" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            tools:text="@string/calcular" android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edTrecho" app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.487"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button" android:autoText="false" android:editable="false"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayou
```

t>

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your manifest file

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

Comment: I put it under the button object and the problem is still happening

Comment: Sure, from which file? the manifest, the script, or the design XML?

Comment: It's in the question

Comment: Can you tell me exactly when you are getting your keyboard enabled automatically?

Comment: When I press tab key, on the `editText` (enter key when on mobile) right before the `button`, the focus switches to the `button` and the keyboard is shown, if I press space, the `button` is clicked. It is working like if it was an `editText`

Comment: Show me your XML.

Comment: Added in the question

Comment: Can you come on for zoom meeting?